# Sharing credentials based on the network profile

Tags: passwords, password-management, credentials, secret-sharing

Is there a way to share logins/passwords with a number of individuals, basing on their public network profile?

Example: a number of people working together in the office should have access credentials to some publicly available webpages. This should be only possible in the office. These credentials can change quite often.

A some kind of password manager would be perfect here, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you never want to give multiple people access to the same account.

Here's an example of why: if someone does something they're not supposed to such as delete data, overwrite information, etc., no one knows who it is and that is a problem within a company. Each person should be liable for their actions, so having individual accounts is the way to go for this. Just create 1 account per person and put them into the same "group". Then assign permissions for that group, allowing all members of the group access to whatever webpages you would like.

**Edit:**

More regarding why shared accounts aren't a good idea:

1. Password changes for security reasons do happen, and someone would have to administer those and then communicate the new password to each user. I don't recommend this as there is never a secure way to tell someone a password. Also who will perform the above actions? A system admin should not be spending time administering this, and one of the users shouldn't do this because it could be similar to one of their personal passwords, thereby putting their emails/facebook/other sites accounts potentially at risk.
2. Also with people sharing a common password, there's greater risk of someone leaking the password (intentionally or non-intentially).